# Showing Image thumbnail with mouse cursor while dragging

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a small WPF application which has a window with an Image control. Image control shows an image from File system. I want user to be able to drag the image and drop to its desktop or anywhere to save it. It's working fine.

But I want to show small image thumbnail along with mouse cursor when user drags it. Just like we drag an image from Windows file explorer to some where else. How to achieve it?

Current Behavior of Drag/Drop

[image: Current Behavior of Drag/Drop]

Desired Behavior

[image: Desired Behavior]

Here is my XAML Code

```
<Grid>
   <Image x:Name="img" Height="100" Width="100" Margin="100,30,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is C# Code

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string imgPath;
        Point start;
        bool dragStart = false;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            imgPath = "C:\\Pictures\\flower.jpg";

            ImageSource imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imgPath));
            img.Source = imageSource;
            window.PreviewMouseMove += Window_PreviewMouseMove;
            window.PreviewMouseUp += Window_PreviewMouseUp;
            window.Closing += Window_Closing;
            img.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += Img_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
        }

        private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            window.PreviewMouseMove -= Window_PreviewMouseMove;
            window.PreviewMouseUp -= Window_PreviewMouseUp;
            window.Closing -= Window_Closing;
            img.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= Img_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;
        }


        private void Window_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!dragStart) return;
            if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                dragStart = false; return;
            }

            Point mpos = e.GetPosition(null);
            Vector diff = this.start - mpos;

            if (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance &&
                Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance)
            {
                string[] file = { imgPath };
                DataObject d = new DataObject();
                d.SetData(DataFormats.Text, file[0]);
                d.SetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, file);
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, d, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }

        private void Img_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.start = e.GetPosition(null);
            dragStart = true;
        }

        private void Window_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            dragStart = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: maybe you'll use `DragDrop.GiveFeedback`. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878004/how-do-i-show-the-item-that-is-being-dragged-in-wpf

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain It's trying to changing mouse cursor, that's not what I need.

Comment: just an idea maybe you can do something like creating a hidden container that shows up while dragging and have child current dragged image and that container follow mouse cursor .

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain The hidden container has a problem that it will remain within the Window. We can not show it outside when mouse leaves the window.

Comment: got something that should work .. try this man https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175870/how-can-i-change-the-mouse-cursor-image

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain Changing cursor is not the solution, there has to be some image dragging with cursor. We can make a hidden image that shows up on drag, but that will work within window, not when mouse goes outside window.

Comment: i know but it isn't by default available in WPF i guess but it does available in UWP cuz i tried. so you have to use some trick and in this case changing the cursor seems working.

Comment: Is it an option to use the [Gong WPF DragnDrop](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop) [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/gong-wpf-dragdrop/)? It's my go-to solution for drag and drop in WPF. If so, you can use a DragAdorner.

Comment: Is the source always a file?

Comment: hey, another trick instead of opening a hidden container just open a `Borderless` window of desired size that have nothing but current image as `Background`. Set window opening position to `Cursor` position (not difficult). and then you can easily make that window follow Cursor Position and as soon drop event triggers you can hide or close that window. This should work.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, will always be a file.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling That will be overkill, I think. And I don't see any example in Gong package that can work in this situation too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officially, you're supposed to use the [IDragSourceHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-idragsourcehelper) interface to add a preview bitmap to a Drag&Drop operation.

Unfortunately, this interface uses [IDataObject::SetData method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-idataobject-setdata) which is not implemented at COM level by the .NET DataObject class, only at .NET level.

The solution is to re-use an IDataObject provided by the Shell instead for any Shell Item (here a file), using the [SHCreateItemFromParsingName function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shcreateitemfromparsingname) and the  [IShellItem::BindToHandler method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitem-bindtohandler).

Note these functions automatically add clipboard formats like FileDrop, but we still have to use IDragSourceHelper to add the preview image.

This is how you can use it:

```
...
// get IDataObject from the Shell so it can handle more formats
var dataObject = DataObjectUtilities.GetFileDataObject(imgPath);

// add the thumbnail to the data object
DataObjectUtilities.AddPreviewImage(dataObject, imgPath);

// start d&d
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, dataObject, DragDropEffects.All);
...
```

And here is the code:

```
public static class DataObjectUtilities
{
    public static void AddPreviewImage(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject dataObject, string imgPath)
    {
        if (dataObject == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataObject));

        var ddh = (IDragSourceHelper)new DragDropHelper();
        var dragImage = new SHDRAGIMAGE();

        // note you should use a thumbnail here, not a full-sized image
        var thumbnail = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imgPath);
        dragImage.sizeDragImage.cx = thumbnail.Width;
        dragImage.sizeDragImage.cy = thumbnail.Height;
        dragImage.hbmpDragImage = thumbnail.GetHbitmap();
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(ddh.InitializeFromBitmap(ref dragImage, dataObject));
    }

    public static System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject GetFileDataObject(string filePath)
    {
        if (filePath == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath));

        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(SHCreateItemFromParsingName(filePath, null, typeof(IShellItem).GUID, out var item));
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(item.BindToHandler(null, BHID_DataObject, typeof(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject).GUID, out var dataObject));
        return (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject)dataObject;
    }

    private static readonly Guid BHID_DataObject = new Guid("b8c0bd9f-ed24-455c-83e6-d5390c4fe8c4");

    [DllImport("shell32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int SHCreateItemFromParsingName(string path, System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IBindCtx pbc, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid, out IShellItem ppv);

    [Guid("43826d1e-e718-42ee-bc55-a1e261c37bfe"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IShellItem
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int BindToHandler(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IBindCtx pbc, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid bhid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppv);

        // other methods are not defined, we don't need them
    }

    [ComImport, Guid("4657278a-411b-11d2-839a-00c04fd918d0")] // CLSID_DragDropHelper
    private class DragDropHelper
    {
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SIZE
    {
        public int cx;
        public int cy;
    }

    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ns-shobjidl_core-shdragimage
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct SHDRAGIMAGE
    {
        public SIZE sizeDragImage;
        public POINT ptOffset;
        public IntPtr hbmpDragImage;
        public int crColorKey;
    }

    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-idragsourcehelper
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("DE5BF786-477A-11D2-839D-00C04FD918D0")]
    private interface IDragSourceHelper
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int InitializeFromBitmap(ref SHDRAGIMAGE pshdi, System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject pDataObject);

        [PreserveSig]
        int InitializeFromWindow(IntPtr hwnd, ref POINT ppt, System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject pDataObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: @SimmonMourier This is closest to what I was looking for. Thank you for your time.

Comment: How could I add more C# object via `SetData()` to this `IDataObject` object?

Comment: @Dia - I don't know what you mean by that you should ask another question

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this. It "picks up" a red transparent square around the mouse position, and "drops" it when you click again.

In reality, you'd want to create the thread doing the interop on click, and stop (not abort) it when you drop.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="Clicker" Click="OnClick">Click Me!</Button>
        <Popup Placement="Absolute" PlacementRectangle="{Binding Placement}" AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen}"
               MouseUp="Cancel">
            <Grid Margin="10" Background="#7fff0000">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="400"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="400"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock>Hello!</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And code behind:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct InteropPoint
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isOpen;
    private int xPos;
    private int yPos;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetCursorPos(ref InteropPoint lpPoint);

    private Thread t;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //Logic
                InteropPoint p = new InteropPoint();
                GetCursorPos(ref p);

                //Update UI
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    XPos = (int) p.X;
                    YPos = (int) p.Y;
                }));

                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        });

        t.Start();
    }

    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        t.Abort();
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsOpen = !IsOpen;
    }

    public int XPos
    {
        get => xPos;
        set
        {
            if (value == xPos) return;
            xPos = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Placement));
        }
    }

    public int YPos
    {
        get => yPos;
        set
        {
            if (value == yPos) return;
            yPos = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Placement));
        }
    }

    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get => isOpen;
        set
        {
            if (value == isOpen) return;
            isOpen = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Rect Placement => new Rect(XPos - 200, YPos - 200, 400, 400);

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void Cancel(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```